# C# Reflection - Get field values from a simple class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class:

```
class A {
    public string a = "A-val" , b = "B-val";
}
```

I want to print the object members **by reflection**

```
//Object here is necessary.
Object data = new A();
FieldInfo[] fields = data.GetType().GetFields();
String str = "";
foreach(FieldInfo f in fields){
    str += f.Name + " = " + f.GetValue(data) + "\r\n";
}
```

Here is the desired result:

```
a = A-val
b = B-val
```

Unfortunately this did not work. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why did it not go well?  What went wrong?

Comment: Your code (with some little modifications to make it compile) does work... what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I haven't tried to compile this but doesn't f.GetValue(data) return an object? should this be .ToString() to put into the string

Comment: @Martin Booth: `GetValue` returns an object, but you can add an object to a string, so that is ok (more or less)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Once fixed to get rid of the errors (lacking a semi-colon and a bad variable name), the code you've posted *does* work - I've just tried it and it showed the names and values with no problems.

My guess is that in reality, you're trying to use fields which aren't public. This code:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = data.GetType().GetFields();
```

... will only get *public* fields. You would normally need to specify that you also want non-public fields:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = data.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                              BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                              BindingFlags.Instance);
```

(I hope you don't *really* have public fields, after all...)

Comment: The fields are public aren't they?

Comment: @MartinBooth: Yeah, I was editing - basically it actually works okay with the code given, but I *suspect* that when it's not working, the OP has private fields.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you had to specify `BindingFlags.Instance` explicitly - I thought that would be the default. Without that flag, though, no fields were returned in my case.

Comment: @Oliver: If you're specifying *any* flags, you need to specify it. The default it something like "public, instance, static".

Comment: @JonSkeet as of today 8/18/2015 the defaults I'm getting are:

BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

Answer (score 3):

Remember when you write fields like :

```
public string VarName{ get; set;}
```

Then actually you have this code(this is what reflection see) :

```
private string _varName;
public string get_VarName(){
....
}
public void set_VarName(strig value){
....
}
```

Comment: Don't want to nitpick on an old post (thread-necro on 3 yr old post), but `public string VarName { get; set; }` is **not** a field at all. It's a property. To be specific, an autoproperty that, just as you write, creates a private field at compile-time. But the property itself is just a property. Just wanted to straighten that out if anyone happens to stumble across this and get confused.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stanislav say, you must keep in mind the backing fields generated by the compiler for properties. If you want to exclude these fields you can use the following code:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = data.GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null)
    .ToArray();
```