# Referencing value by variable name

Tags: vb.net, variables

Is it possible to obtain the content of a variable by referencing to its name. 
I have a bunch of variables like

```
Dim _tipoEntero As String = "^[0-9].$"
Dim _tipoTelefono As String = "^[0-9]{6}$"
```

and I'm trying to reference as something like

```
myValue = GetVariableValue("_tipo" + validationString)
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do that without using property's, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338018/how-to-get-a-property-value-using-reflection) , Edit: while writing this i came up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649324/c-sharp-reflection-get-field-values-from-a-simple-class)

Comment: Do those really need to be variables?  If you are just associating names with strings, you could use a hash table.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    Dim tipos As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    tipos.Add("Entero", "^[0-9].$")
    tipos.Add("Telefono", "^[0-9]{6}$")

    myValue = tipo(validationString)
```

Comment: Alternative: Store regex objects instead of strings. `Dim tipos As New Dictionary(Of String, Regex)`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for your question is "Yes" it is possible :

```
myValue = Me.GetType.GetField("_tipo" & validationString).GetValue(Me)
```

And we can make more effective :

```
myValue = Me.GetType.GetField("_tipo" & validationString, Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(Me)
```

I set the binding flags to catch both public and private variables, and also ignoring the case sensitive of your search, so it doesn't matter you type "_tipo" or "_TiPo".

This is an answer for your question, but I didn't suggest you a better way to do your task.