# Select Variable by its Name and Set

Tags: vb.net

```
Module MyModule
Public Property alpha As String
Public Property beta As String
Public Property charlie As String
End MyModule


Public Class MyClass
Sub New()
Dim variableName as String = "beta"
MyModule.GetField(variableName) = "new value"
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm looking for a way to set the value of a variable in the module. But only the variable with the given variable name. The example above obviously does not work, but it provides an idea of my goal.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1

    Sub New()
        SetVariableByVariableName("beta", "new value")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetVariableByVariableName(ByVal variableName As String, ByVal value As String)
        Dim myFieldInfo As FieldInfo = GetType(MyModule).GetField(variableName, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static)
        If myFieldInfo IsNot Nothing Then
            myFieldInfo.SetValue(Nothing, value)
            Console.WriteLine($"The value of {variableName} is now: {GetType(MyModule).GetField(variableName).GetValue(Nothing)}")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {variableName} does not exist in MyModule.")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class


Module MyModule
    Public Property alpha As String
    Public Property beta As String
    Public Property charlie As String
End Module
```

Comment: I haven't tested but I think that you may be able to pass `Nothing`. Members of modules are effectively the same as `Shared` members of classes, so you would set a module field by Reflection in the same way you would set a `Shared` class field. I've never actually done that but I expect that you do it by passing no object to the first parameter of `SetValue`.

Comment: The documentation for that `SetValue` method says this: *"This method will assign value to the field reflected by this instance on object obj. If the field is static, obj will be ignored"*. `static` is the C# version of `Shared`. That seems to suggest that you pass absolutely anything as the first argument, but `Nothing` seems to be the obvious and sensible choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on my [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311594/2330053):

MyModule:

```
Module MyModule
    Public Property alpha As String
    Public Property beta As String = "default beta"
    Public Property charlie As String
End Module
```

Module1, which accesses the above "by name":

```
Imports System.Reflection
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Module Property accessed directly: " & MyModule.beta)
        Console.WriteLine("Module Property accessed 'by name': " & GetModulePropertyByName("MyModule", "beta"))

        Console.WriteLine("Changing value...")
        SetModulePropertyByName("MyModule", "beta", "Can you hear me now?")

        Console.WriteLine("Module Property accessed directly: " & MyModule.beta)
        Console.WriteLine("Module Property accessed 'by name': " & GetModulePropertyByName("MyModule", "beta"))

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Press any key to quit...")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetModulePropertyByName(ByVal moduleName As String, ByVal moduleField As String, ByVal value As String)
        Dim myType As Type = Nothing
        Dim myModule As [Module] = Nothing
        For Each x In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules
            For Each y In x.GetTypes
                If y.Name.ToUpper = moduleName.ToUpper Then
                    myType = y
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not IsNothing(myType) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not IsNothing(myType) Then
            Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Instance
            Dim pi As PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty(moduleField, flags)
            If Not IsNothing(pi) Then
                pi.SetValue(Nothing, value)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetModulePropertyByName(ByVal moduleName As String, ByVal moduleField As String) As Object
        Dim O As Object = Nothing

        Dim myType As Type = Nothing
        Dim myModule As [Module] = Nothing
        For Each x In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules
            For Each y In x.GetTypes
                If y.Name.ToUpper = moduleName.ToUpper Then
                    myType = y
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not IsNothing(myType) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not IsNothing(myType) Then
            Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Instance
            Dim pi As PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty(moduleField, flags)
            If Not IsNothing(pi) Then
                O = pi.GetValue(Nothing)
            End If
        End If

        Return O
    End Function

End Module
```

Output:

```
Module Property accessed directly: default beta
Module Property accessed 'by name': default beta
Changing value...
Module Property accessed directly: Can you hear me now?
Module Property accessed 'by name': Can you hear me now?

Press any key to quit...
```