# C# Is there a way to obtain a reference for a field from a class and use the reference to call methods?

Tags: c#

C# Question .Net version 4.6.1

I have a class as shown below and in a function I create an instance of the class.  I would like to create a reference to field(s) from the class instance and call the method "Insert" on the class variables "Name" and "Description".

I used a google search for: "Get reference to class field via 
reflection in C#". I did find information on stackoverflow for reflection but it does not talk about calling methods. I was able to use some of it to find what looks like a pointer.  However I could not make it all the way to calling methods on the reference.  I either am asking Google the wrong question or what I am trying to do is not possible.
[C# Reflection - Get field values from a simple class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649324/c-sharp-reflection-get-field-values-from-a-simple-class)

```
    Class AClass1
    {
        public String Action = String.Empty;
        public List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> Description = new  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        public List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> Name= new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }


    // Psudo code:
    // The code has been reduced down to show the problem.  Error handling
    // etc has been removed. This may not compile because I had to 
    // reduce down the code to show what I am trying to accomplish. Any
    // suggestions for creating a reference to a class variable and calling
    // its methods would be appreciated.  If needed I can create a small 
    // sample that does compile but I think the sample provided shows 
    // what I am trying to accomplish.  If not let me know and I will
    // scale down further.


public void ProcessFeature1(String fieldName, String value1, String value2)
{
    AClass1 featureToManage = new AClass1();

    KeyValuePair<string, string> entry = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(value1, value2);
    if (entry != null)
    {
        // something along these lines is preferred if possible
        var ptrField = featureToManage.GetType().GetField(fieldName).FieldHandle;
        if (ptrField != null)
        {
            // the problem is figuring how to turn the value from reflection into
            // something I can call directly.  I have tried casting to the same
            // type as the variable in the class (not shown here) 
            // but it did not work or I did it wrong.  When I say it does not
            // work the run-time information does not show the method and the
            // compiler complains generally saying no such method Insert found.
            ptrField.Insert(0, entry);
        }
        else
        {
            // this works but would prefer to lookup the
            // the field in the class and call methods so I
            // 1. have less code
            // 2. do not have to hard code the name of the field.
            switch (fieldName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    {
                        featureToManage.Name.Insert(0, entry);
                        break;
                    }
                case "Description":
                    {
                        featureToManage.Description.Insert(0, entry);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        // something bad happened
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Once you have gotten the `FieldInfo` from the Type using `GetField()`, you just need to call its `GetValue()` method, passing the object instance that you want to get the field value from (in this case `featureToManage`), and then cast the resulting value to the appropriate type (in this case `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`).

Here is what it looks like in code:

```
public void ProcessFeature1(string fieldName, string value1, string value2)
{
    AClass1 featureToManage = new AClass1();

    // Get the FieldInfo for the requested fieldName
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = featureToManage.GetType().GetField(fieldName);

    // Use the fieldInfo to get the value of the field from the target instance
    var targetList = (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)fieldInfo.GetValue(featureToManage);

    // now we can use the value as normal
    var entry = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(value1, value2);
    targetList.Insert(0, entry);
}
```

Note that in C# 6 you can use the `nameof()` operator to avoid hardcoding class, field and property names when using reflection, e.g.:

```
ProcessFeature1(nameof(AClass1.Description), "foo", "bar");
```