# How to get the value of a field c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and i have a class full of gameObjects, i want to take an instance of that class and compare all the values against one i already have. However in order to do this i need to have the filed value, how do i get this?, Here's my curent code:

```
void UpdatePage() {
  foreach(FieldInfo field in Pages.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
    Page = field.GetValue();
  }

}
```

Comment: _"filed value"_?  Is that a typo?  Did you mean "field value"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Reflection - Get field values from a simple class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649324/c-sharp-reflection-get-field-values-from-a-simple-class)

Comment: I would recommend changing your strategy completely. Do not make the fields you are calling static, instead make them instance singletons instead. This will let you hold a `Page[]` in `Pages` and you can foreach over the array instead of being forced to use reflection.

Comment: why even use reflection for this? I would rather implement `Equals` in the class itself where you have access to all private fields anyway... could you please post a minimal **complete** working code so we can reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetField()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_FieldInfo_GetValue_System_Object_) method requires an instance argument:

```cs
var val = field.GetValue(Pages);
```

Here's a self-contained example (also [a link to .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sEgDQi)):

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var item = new SomeType();
        item.FieldA = "hi";
        item.FieldB = "bye";
        
        foreach(var field in item.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) {
            var val = field.GetValue(item);
            Console.WriteLine("In the 'item' instance, field " + field.Name + " has value " + val);
        }
    }
}

public class SomeType {
    public string FieldA;
    public string FieldB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the target instance to `GetValue()` (`null` for static fields):

```
Page = field.GetValue(field.IsStatic ? null : Pages);
```